# How is re projection usually implemented in remeshing?

Tags: mathematics, computational-geometry, algorithm, geometry

I was reading "Polygon Mesh Processing" and in chapter 5 the authors present this little algorithm:

```
remesh(target edge length)
  low = 4/5 * target edge length
  high = 4/3 * target edge length
  for i = 0 to 10 do
    split long edges(high)
    collapse short edges(low,high)
    equalize valences()
    tangential relaxation()
    project to surface()
```

They provide pseudocode and explanations for all steps except the last one. I assume that the reprojection must be done using the input mesh as a reference. Do you use some kind of BVH, find the triangle closest to the point and project to the plane?